# How to remove the response header, such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I know that the zuul gateway can be removed by configuration, but how is springcloud-gateway implemented?

zuul:
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie
  ignored-headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with `RemoveRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory` or `RemoveResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory` or `RemoveHopByHopHeadersFilter`.

Please check [spring-cloud-gateway guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#_removehopbyhopheadersfilter_gatewayfilter_factory). Choose a filter that fits your use case.

you can configure like below.

```
# RemoveHopByHopHeadersFilter
spring.cloud.gateway.filter.remove-hop-by-hop: 
  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials

# RemoveResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-route
          uri: http://test.org
          filters:
            - RemoveResponseHeader= Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

`RemoveHopByHopHeadersFilter` is applied to all routes by default. But If you want to apply `RemoveRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory` or `RemoveResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory` to all routes, you have to set `spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters` property.